# Jquery Overlay with Button (ImageButton/AspButton)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, button, overlay

I wanna use a button in asp.net. When I ckick on it, an overlay shall occur and the overlay shall filled with data.

How Can I do this with Jquery?

My Problem is that, when I click on the button, the whole page is send back to server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you have "return false" in your binded function for click?

Comment: @juraj - it's a shame you didn't add an answer, I can't upvote you that way.

Comment: but I can upvote YOU :) i just wanted facts, whether the problem is somewhere else than simple "return false" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `asp:Button` will create a postback when clicked. You can use JavaScript to prevent that, as @juraj suggests in a comment, by returning `false` at the end of the click function you bind to it.

Another option is to use an ordinary button instead on an asp button:

```
<input type='button' value='Click Me' id='justButton' />
```

You can also add such a button using the designer (if you prefer), under `HTML > Input (Button)`.